# Curl command only returns limited set of data

Tags: curl

I am running a simple curl commmand on a Redhat system with mongodb but it only returns a limited number of data.

curl  http://192.168.0.2:8300/assets

Is there an option to curl that would fix this, an API limitation or setting or something else?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

curl asks for the resource identified by the URL and returns the entire thing the server sends back.

If that is not good enough, you better use another URL or fix the server to return what you want.